# Has anyone here used QuickAlerts?

Tags: transactions, events

How can I track transactions from and to a wallet address? / How can I track smart contract events in real-time as they happen? Renat Ghoste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used QuickAlerts and I find it very useful. The competing offerings I've tried are not as real-time or are quite limiting on what you can be notified of.

Using it is straightforward if you understand the standard fields available in RPC calls. With QuickAlerts, you specify an "expression" as to what you want to be alerted on and a destination webhook where you want the alert to be sent to. You can set up this monitoring either through the QuickNode UI or through a [REST API](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/rest-api/getting-started).

I believe your question is about how to configure the expression on Ethereum, since we're in Ethereum StackExchange so we'll focus there.

The expression is configured with variables you'd find in RPC calls for blocks (i.e `block_hash`, `block_number`), transactions (i.e `tx_from`, `tx_value`), and transaction receipts (i.e `tx_logs_topic0`, `tx_logs_data`). See the full list [here](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/quickalerts-expressions/building-expressions).

In the following examples, we'll assume you want to monitor address `0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045`

### How can I track transactions FROM a wallet address?

```
(tx_from == '0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B')
```

### How can I track transactions TO a wallet address?

```
(tx_to == '0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B')
```

### Monitoring a wallet for NFT transfers

This one is a bit more complex and requires an understanding of how transactions work on the blockchain. Since NFT Transfers can happen in multiple formats and include interactions with smart contracts, the address you want to monitor will not always be the tx_to or tx_from values. Instead, the ERC-721 and ERC-1155 standards include the to and from addresses in the transaction log topics. We can see a simple example [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x347bc4773cb80366c18beee32d3c2849ade73994b8d5142b6e1d09d5e8ca8dc4#eventlog).

**Log topic 0** represents the hash of the function called within the smart contract. For Transfer, that hash is `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

**Log topic 1** represents the address sending the NFT

**Log topic 2** represents the address receiving the NFT

So in the expression, you will check to see if the log topic 0 is indicating a transfer, AND (using `&&`) you'll check to see if the address we want to monitor is the sender OR (using `||`) the receiver in log topics 1 and 2.

```
(tx_logs_topic0 == '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef') && ((tx_logs_topic1 =~ 'Ab5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B') || (tx_logs_topic2 =~ 'Ab5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B'))
```

*note: log topics are encoded HEX values and the true value on chain is `0x000000000000000000000000a435eb4bb25c8420bc6561a8f3f38935f1b68a27`, you can either specify that exact value with `==` or use a regex match like we did in the example above with `=~` with a substring.*

### Bringing it all together

An expression to monitor NFT Transfers as well as transactions would be as follows

```
(tx_from == '0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B') || (tx_to == '0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B') || ((tx_logs_topic0 == '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef') && ((tx_logs_topic1 =~ 'Ab5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B') || (tx_logs_topic2 =~ 'Ab5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B')))
```

More resources on QuickAlerts:

- [QuickAlerts documentation](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/getting-started)
- [Playlist of YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT2H_0otcvBTHGSPrLSV69ReSZF1gZFIw) including how to set up notifications to Telegram, Email, and Discord using both the UI and REST API
- [Spanish]: [Serverless function](https://github.com/irwingtello/serverlessWebHook) and [Written Guide](https://irwingtello.hashnode.dev/monitorea-eventos-en-tiempo-real-en-blockchain-con-quickalerts) for Telegram notifications

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Hope there continues to be questions you are interested in answering :)